How to change sample rate without altering the samples, just to increase the duration of reproduction in Audacity
I have a a wav file that i record to my proyect, i have a file written to 5000 samples per second (sps), i want to save the same file, but changing the sample rate to 100 sps without altering the samples, just to increase the timme of reproduction.
I already tried with the REsample in Track menu, but that just change the samaple with the same duration of the file, i want to wide the file duration with the same samples just decreasing the sample rate,and keeping the same samples, so the time get increased x50
